# Using SortedSet with Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I would like to use a SortedSet as a Collection with Spring JPA…

```
@SortNatural
@ElementCollection
private SortedSet<Report> activities = new TreeSet<>();
```

but Spring only let's me specify [Collection, List and Set].

I mean Set does work, Hibernate internally uses a wrapper class called PersistentSortedSet when I add the `@SortNatural` annotation, but I also want to use methods SortedSet provides, like `last()`. Specifing SortedSet doesn't let me compile and a cast from Set to TreeSet (SortedSet) doesn't work either.

```
((TreeSet<Report>) repairableActivities).last();
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSortedSet cannot be cast to class java.util.TreeSet (org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSortedSet is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.TreeSet is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I found threads with similar issues ([Changing from Collection to SortedSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092672/changing-from-collection-to-sortedset/10107409#10107409)) but there was no real solution.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't do that. Rather use List and in getter method convert List into SortedSet. List data order naturally.

Comment: I only wanted to expose the last element of the set. The best thing I could think of was still using SortedSet but reversing the order using a comparator.

Comment: Why are you casting to `TreeSet`? can't you cast it to `SortedSet` since  `PersistentSortedSet`  implements `SortedSet`?

Comment: Yeah, that worked. I thought I tried that out :D But now it's perfect, thank you

Comment: If you want only last element fetching full set is useless, try to query for that.